# Getting a result set from a SQL SERVER stored procedure using GROOVY SQL

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, grails, groovy

I'm trying to get a result set from a stored procedure in SQL SERVER (2005 I believe) from within my GRAILS app. (Grails 1.3.2, Groovy 1.7.6)

The stored procedure runs fine with any query browser, I use SQLDBX, it returns the result set as I'd expected all the time.

From within my app however it will throw an ERROR if the procedure actually modifies data, but if it doesn't it will not throw this ERROR and will return the result set as I'd like.

Now I can't post the procedure here but this is a modified ver. that does approximately the same thing.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [procedure1]
@year VARCHAR(4)
as
begin
DECLARE @var1 INT
DECLARE @var2 varchar(50)
DECLARE @counter INT

SET @counter=0

set @cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD for
        select *
        FROM [table1] as t1
        INNER JOIN [table2] as t2
        ON t1.f_id = t2.f_id
        WHERE t1.year = @year
open @cursor
set @date = GETDATE()

fetch next from @cursor into @var1,@var2
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    select @numRows = count(id) from table1
    if(@numRows = 0)
    begin
        SET @counter=@counter+1
    END

    fetch next from @cursor into @var1,@var2
end

close @cursor
deallocate @cursor
SELECT @counter AS 'count'
return 0
END
GO
```

The modified ver doesn't make much sense but it performs the same actions.

From within my GRAILS app I'm doing the equivalent of

```
Sql conn = new Sql(dataSource) //A valid declaration  
try{  
  def results = conn.rows("execute [dbo].[procedure1] @year='2011'")  
  println("${results}")  
}  
catch(SQLException e){  
  println(e.getMessage())  
}
```

Every time this runs and the counter was modified (aka it's not zero) it throws the exception. However if I run 
`execute procedure1 @year='2011'` from SQLDBX, and the counter isn't zero, it returns as I would expect.

I tried a few different methods from the Groovy SQL class as well and all of them seem to throw this exception or aren't what I'm looking for.

The exception is

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException - The statement did not return a result set.
```

If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: Are you possibly returning multiple result sets, one for each `SELECT` that you're running in the procedure? I'd try replacing `select @numRows = count(id) from table1` with `set @numRows = (select count(id) from table1)`.

Comment: That had no effect, still gives the "The statement did not return a result set" error. It still completes the procedure too.

Comment: I've got a work-around in place, to basically query the affected table before the stored proc, then after, and take a difference of the counts. I'd really like to get the result set working though since when this table gets quite larger, these two extra queries are going to cost precious time. Thanks.

Comment: As an update to this, I guess I forgot to mention that I'm running in an IBM Websphere. The GRAILS app uses JNDI sources, and in WAS the JNDI source for the main SQL Server database is using an out-dated JDBC driver. I can't run this locally (because of some external configuration stuff) or update the driver on the WAS, so I can't test to see if it's the driver or GROOVY. I'm stuck using the work around unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Add `SET NOCOUNT ON` after the `AS` in your sproc.  Adding this will tell sql server not to return the number of modified records in the sproc.

Here is the documention...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The executeQuery() is intended to be used with queries that return a ResultSet, typically SELECT statements.

The executeUpdate() is intended for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or DDL statements that return update counts.

Both of the above (ResultSets and update counts) are considered by JDBC to be as "results". For queries that return multiple results it requires we invoke execute().

If stored procedure makes use of temp tables, probably it returns an update count first, followed by a ResultSet. You should use execute() to run query, call getMoreResults() to skip the update count and then call getResultSet() to obtain the **ResultSet you want**. The problem here is we have to do trial and error by calling getMoreResults() multiple times to fetch result set we want by calling getResultSet().

Instead of above way of trial and error, you can suppress all the extra "query results" by specifying "**SET NOCOUNT ON**".

Changes required,

1. Put your logic in SP "SPCHILD". This Stored procedure will have logic along with temp table creation.
2. Create a SP "SPPARENT" as below,

   ```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPPARENT]    @Id int = NULL
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXEC(' SPCHILD @Id = ' + @Id)
    END
   ```

   From parent SP "SPPARENT" you have to call your actual SP i.e. "SPCHILD".
3. From your JDBC code make a SP call to "SPPARENT".

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493917/how-to-run-stored-procedure-from-groovy-that-returns-multiple-resultsets/19268309#19268309) for a util which can process stored procedure ResultSets in a similar way to `groovy.sql.Sql`